# Connecting to database and reading data in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, sql-server

What am I doing wrong here? I get an error:

> incorrect syntax near =

on this line of code:

```
Dim SqlDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLCommad.ExecuteReader()
```

My code:

```
Dim Username = TUserName.Text
Dim Password = TPassword.Text

Dim SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBConnection.ToString)
Dim SQLCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from " + My.Settings.TableName.ToString + "Where EmpID = " + Username, SqlConnection)
SqlConnection.Open()

Dim SqlDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader

While (SqlDataReader.Read)
      If Username = SqlDataReader(1).ToString And Password = SqlDataReader(20).ToString Then
         If eEncrypt(Username, Password) Then
            MsgBox("You are NOT logged in")
         Else
            MsgBox("You are logged in")
         End If
      End If
End While

SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Can you update your post with fixed by @Horaciux code which cause the `exactly same` error.

Comment: the `Username` is a text, and you are not warp it on SQL with "``", beside that bug your code is open to SQL Injection.

Comment: also the `MsgBox` is not work on asp.net

Comment: this will fix the error, but you need to make it with sql parametres `New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from " + My.Settings.TableName.ToString + " Where EmpID = '" + Username + "'", SqlConnection)`  (add the ` and extra space on where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, see how a parammeter is added

```
Dim Username = TUserName.Text
Dim Password = TPassword.Text

Dim SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.DBConnection.ToString)
Dim SQLCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from " + My.Settings.TableName.ToString + "Where EmpID = @Username", SqlConnection)

SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username)
SqlConnection.Open()

Dim SqlDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader()

While (SqlDataReader.Read)
      If Username = SqlDataReader(1).ToString And Password = SqlDataReader(20).ToString Then
         If eEncrypt(Username, Password) Then
            MsgBox("You are NOT logged in")
         Else
            MsgBox("You are logged in")
         End If
      End If
End While

SqlConnection.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you miss parenthesis

```
Dim SqlDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLCommad.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Yes exactly, the same

Comment: @PieterdeVries I'm confused now. It's an error before compiling or in running time?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

Dim SQLCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from " + My.Settings.TableName.ToString + "Where EmpID = " + Username, SqlConnection)

should be

Dim SQLCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from " + My.Settings.TableName.ToString + "Where EmpID = '" + Username + "'", SqlConnection)

posted from mobile.